# The app keeps restarting itself even after closing

Tags: android, restart, system-services

I am trying to make an app with floating widget on top of the screen all the time. Looking through examples online I finally assembled a basic thing to start with.

However, whenever I try to close the app, it keeps restarting itself unless I force stop it by going into "App info."

Let me try to post my codes here...
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/*  Permission request code to draw over other apps  */
private static final int DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1222;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/*  start floating widget service  */
public void createFloatingWidget(View view) {
    //Check if the application has draw over other apps permission or not?
    //This permission is by default available for API<23. But for API > 23
    //you have to ask for the permission in runtime.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        //If the draw over permission is not available open the settings screen
        //to grant the permission.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else
        //If permission is granted start floating widget service
        startFloatingWidgetService();

}

/*  Start Floating widget service and finish current activity */
private void startFloatingWidgetService() {
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingWidgetService.class));
    //startService(new Intent(context, ServiceChatHead.class));
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        //Check if the permission is granted or not.
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            //If permission granted start floating widget service
            startFloatingWidgetService();
        else
            //Permission is not available then display toast
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.draw_other_app_permission_denied),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And FloatingWidgetService

```
public class FloatingWidgetService extends Service {



    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatImage;

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;


@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
        chatImage = new ImageView(this);
        chatImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.inosukes);



        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,

                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        chatImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    // single tap
                    if (chatImage != null) windowManager.removeView(chatImage);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // for move and drag
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initialX = params.x;
                            initialY = params.y;
                            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                            params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                            windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatImage, params);
                            return true;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });


        windowManager.addView(chatImage, params);
    }


private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatImage != null) windowManager.removeView(chatImage);


    //this is not helping to close the app?
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If method `startService()` is used to start the service in other places,it will restart itself even though the activity binded to it was destroyed.So make sure you start the service only by `bindService()` method.

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514287/android-service-startservice-and-bindservice/3514742#3514742) SO Question also..

Comment: Thank you for your reply and kind supply of further reference. I will try to learn bindService().